# My try isn't catching my error messages,,,

Tags: c#

When I run my code I can enter any character and it gives me a letter grade back, which it isn't supposed to. What am I missing?

```
namespace ProjException
/* Include exception handling techniques with the traditional averaging program. 
 * Allow the user to input multiple sets of scores.
 * Ensure that only numeric values are entered and that values fall between 0 and 100. 
 * Calculate the average for each set of values. 
 * Test the result to determine whether an A, B, C, D, or F should be recorded. The scoring rubric is as follows: A—90–100; B—80–89; C—70–79; D—60–69; F < 60.
 * Your solution should include exception-handling techniques with a minimum of three appropriate catch clauses.
 */
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variables Declared
            int grade = 0;
            int total = 0;
            int count = 0;
            double average;
            string letterGrade = "F";

            while (grade != -99)
            {
                try
                {
                   Console.Write("Enter a Grade 0-100 -99 to quit: ");
                   grade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                   if ((grade != -99 && grade < 0) || grade > 100)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

                   if (grade != -99)
                   {
                        total += grade;
                        count++;
                   }
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Grade must be a number");
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Grade must be between 0 and 100 or -99 to quit");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Some other error occurred");
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

                average = (double)total / count;

                if (average >= 90)
                    letterGrade = "A";
                else if (average >= 80)
                    letterGrade = "B";
                else if (average >= 70)
                    letterGrade = "C";
                else if (average >= 60)
                    letterGrade = "D";
                else
                    letterGrade = "F";

                Console.WriteLine("Your letter grade is " + letterGrade);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if `count` isn't changed, you're dividing by zero after catch `average = (double)total / count;`

Comment: You catch the exception - but then still print "Your letter grade is ...". Did you mean to have a `continue;` statement in each catch block, to make it go back to the start of the `while` loop?

Comment: You should not use Exceptions for validation - there is really nothing exceptional about users entering bad data.  Use `Integer.TryParse()` instead - it is made so you can *avoid* exceptions.

Comment: Thanks  Plutonix. That's a good idea. Thanks Daisy and Valentin. I appreciate your time. I'll be more specific with my questions next time. I'm still kinda in the beginning stages of C# skills. I really like though.

Answer (score -1):

You don't change the flow, when you catch an exception (which works fine). The program will continue after your try catch-blocks and eventually reach the output of the grade. One way here is to use [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) in the catch blocks, to cause the loop to end the current iteration and start the next from the beginning.

Comment: I don't think I did but i'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: try using goto statment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto

Comment: @user123456 but `goto` is not `IDisposable`. (hey, seriously?)

Comment: @user123456: Even loop control statements are considered spaghetti by some. `goto` is even more spaghetti. And it's not needed here as the beginning of the loop block is needed, which doesn't need to be addressed by a label when `continue` is used. That way it stays there and doesn't jump somewhere else when the label was accidentally relocated. => I can't see why to favour `goto` over `continue` here.

Comment: @stickybit my bad continue is the best solution, how ever he has to check if count and total not equal to zero before calculating the average.other wise it will throw another exception

Comment: @ user123456: Yes, your're right, that's another issue here.